# Transform pandas column with Json content

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that has 3 columns:
`id` `external_id_client` `custom_attributes`

| id | external_id_client | custom_attributes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2530 | [{'teste_id': 19225, 'custom_attribute_id': 47}] |
| 2 | 4050 | [{'teste_id': 1834, 'custom_attribute_id': 53}] |
| 3 | 4953 | [{'teste_id': 3295, 'custom_attribute_id': 8565}] |

The problem is that the `custom_attributes` column is coming with a list and a json inside. I need to transform this column with the content in json into columns, with the key being the column name and content being the value.

This is the expected output, could you help me on how to do this in code?

| id | external_id_client | teste_id | custom_attribute_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2530 | 19225 | 47 |
| 2 | 4050 | 1834 | 53 |
| 3 | 4953 | 3295 | 8565 |

Comment: could you include the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`. As of now, it's not clear what datatype you have in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every element of the column custom_attributes contains a list with a dictionary with the same keys, you could simply iterate over the keys and successively add new columns for each key and then drop the redundant initial column, as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2530, [{'teste_id': 19225, 'custom_attribute_id': 47}]],
    [2, 4050, [{'teste_id': 1834, 'custom_attribute_id': 53}]],
    [3, 4953, [{'teste_id': 3295, 'custom_attribute_id': 8565}]]
], index=[1, 2, 3], columns=['id', 'external_id_client', 'custom_attributes'])

def transform(df):
    df2 = df.copy()
    keys = list(df['custom_attributes'].values[0][0].keys())
    for key in keys:
        df2[key] = df['custom_attributes'].apply(lambda x: x[0][key])
    df2.drop(columns=['custom_attributes'], inplace=True)
    return df2

df2 = transform(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) you can extract the json column:

```
df[['teste_id', 'custom_attribute_id']] = df['custom_attributes'].apply(
lambda x: pd.Series(x[0].values()))
```

And finally [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the column:

```
df.drop('custom_attributes', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with Pandas string methods:

```py
 (df
.assign(teste_id = df.custom_attributes.str[0].str['teste_id'], 
        custom_attribute_id = df.custom_attributes.str[0].str['custom_attribute_id'])
.drop(columns = 'custom_attributes')
)

   id  external_id_client  teste_id  custom_attribute_id
1   1                2530     19225                   47
2   2                4050      1834                   53
3   3                4953      3295                 8565
```